# Rank function for date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, window-functions

I have the following code for example:

```
SELECT id, order_day, purchase_id FROM d
```

`customer_id` and `purchase_id` are unique. Each `customer_id` could have multiple `purchase_id`. Assume every one has made at least 5 orders.

Now, I just want to pull the first 5 purchase IDs of *each customers ID* (this depends on the earliest dates of purchases). I want the result to look like this:

```
 id | purchase_id | rank
-------------------------
  A |  WERFEW43   |  1
  A |  ERTGDSFV   |  3
  A |  FDGRT45    |  2
  A |  BRTE4TEW   |  4
  A |  DFGDV      |  5
  B |  DSFSF      |  1
  B |  CF345      |  2
  B |  SDFSDFSDFS |  4
```

I thought of Ranking `order_day`, but my knowledge is not good enough to pull this off.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,purchase_id, rank() over (order by order_day)
from d
```

you also can try `dense_rank() over (order by order_day)` and `row_number() over (order by order_day)` and choose which one will be more suitable for you

Comment: This does not work. Only returned 5 orders in total based on day only, not by id.

Comment: @VDL `over (partition by id order by order_day)` will help. And to return only 5 rows you should add `WHERE` condition. See @dnoeth answer

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
 ( SELECT
      id
     ,order_day
     ,purchase_id
     ,row_number()                    -- ranking
      over (partition by id           -- each customer
            order by order_day) as rn -- based on oldest dates
   FROM d
 ) as dt
where rn <= 5
```